shiny.fluent and imola headache - pushing page beyond footer
I've come across what seems to be some sort of anomaly whereby on the homepage when I input content, it pushes the end of the page beyond the footer in equal measure to how much content has been entered.
I can't replicate it, and through attempting to replicate what I'm seeing is any page I route to homepage acquires this anomaly.
What could be different about a homepage routing?
Attempting to replicate below, it works fine. Page ends at footer.
When I build this exact home page from the attached code into my app it causes the issue.
When I re-route my other pages to be the home page the anomaly appears again, so it's nothing to do with the code per page function, it's something else, but what?
What could be causing just the routed home_page to scroll beyond the footer though? if not the css, not something off with grid etc
library(shiny)
library(shiny.fluent)
library(shiny.router)
library(imola)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(highcharter)
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(readr)
library(forcats)
library(purrr)
library(glue)
library(patchwork)
library(sjmisc)
library(scales)
library(ggthemes)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(forecast)

# source('functions.R')
# source('uiContent.R')

# ---- creating test dataframe

dates <- seq(as.Date('2017-01-01'), as.Date('2018-12-01'), by = 'month')

dates <- as.data.frame(dates)

test <- tibble::tribble(
  ~a,     ~b,      ~c,
  2166,     42,      155,
  2044,     59,      193,
  1851,     30,      113,
  1830,     60,      348,
  1739,     70,      233,
  1783,     44,      258,
  1839,     64,      234,
  1873,     27,      157,
  1930,     30,      330,
  2011,     64,      296,
  2655,     37,      297,
  2290,     58,      132,
  2166,     45,      135,
  2009,     72,      120,
  1851,     20,      203,
  3830,     33,      328,
  1639,     40,      243,
  1783,     54,      228,
  4839,     34,      164,
  1873,     29,      657,
  1630,     20,      230,
  2061,     62,      226,
  2255,     47,      117,
  2340,     58,      172)


test <- cbind(dates, test)

test2 <- test %>% mutate('Year'= year(dates))

# ---- SELECT DATA COLS to view in Sidebar Data Table ----

details_list_columns <- tibble(
  fieldName = c("a", "b", "c"),
  name = c("A", "B", "C"),
  key = fieldName
)


# ---- Create Charts ----


line_graph <- function(test, title) {
  
  test <- test
  
  # ---- create series array object (an object with 'members')
  series = list(
    list(
      name = "A",
      data  = test$a
    ),
    list(
      name = "B",
      data = test$b
    ),
    list(
      name = "C",
      data  = test$c
    )
  )
  
  # ---- plot
  highchart() %>% 
    hc_chart(backgroundColor = "white") %>% 
    hc_xAxis(categories = test$dates,
             dateTimeLabelFormats = list(month = '%b\'%y'), 
             type = "datetime", 
             tickInterval = 2) %>% 
    hc_yAxis(name = "Total Hours") %>% 
    hc_add_series_list(series) %>% 
    hc_plotOptions(
      line = list(
        marker = list(
          lineWidth = 2,
          enabled = FALSE
        )
      )
    ) %>% 
    hc_size(height = 420) %>% 
    hc_legend(align = "left") %>% 
    hc_title(text = title, align = "left",style = list(color ='#344a5e',
                                                       fontFamily = "Georgia",
                                                       fontWeight = 600)) %>% 
    hc_credits(enabled = TRUE,
               text = "Sources:",
               style = list(fontSize = "10px")) %>% 
    hc_add_theme(hc_theme_smpl()) 
}


stacked_chart <- function(test, title){
  
  
    test <- test
    
    # ---- creating stacking plot
    highchart() %>% 
      hc_chart(type = "column") %>%
      hc_plotOptions(column = list(stacking = "normal")) %>% 
      hc_xAxis(categories = test$dates,
               dateTimeLabelFormats = list(month = '%b\'%y'), 
               type = "datetime", 
               tickInterval = 2) %>% 
      hc_yAxis(title = list(text = "Testing Totals",
                            margin = 20), opposite = TRUE) %>% 
      hc_add_series(name = "a",
                    data = test$a) %>% 
      hc_add_series(name = "b", 
                    data = test$b) %>% 
      hc_add_series(name = "c",
                    data = test$c) %>% 
      hc_title(text = 'Stacking', align = "left") %>%
      hc_credits(enabled = TRUE,
                 text = "Sources: ",
                 href = 'https://www.',
                 style = list(fontSize = "10px")) %>% 
      hc_legend(align = 'left') %>% 
      hc_add_theme(thm)

}

plot_cluster <- function(year1, year2, test2, title){
  
  year1 <- year1
  year2 <- year2
  
  test2 <- test2
  
  # ---- year 1 data wrangle and calculate median 
  year1_median <- test2 %>% 
    group_by(Year) %>% 
    summarise(across(where(is.numeric), median)) %>% 
    filter(Year == year1) %>% 
    pivot_longer(!Year, names_to = "Type", values_to = "Median Hours") %>% 
    mutate(Type = fct(Type), Year = as.character(Year))
  
  
  # ---- year 2 data wrangle and calculate median 
  year2_median <- test2 %>% 
    group_by(Year) %>% 
    summarise(across(where(is.numeric), median)) %>% 
    filter(Year == year2) %>%  
    pivot_longer(!Year, names_to = "Type", values_to = "Median Hours") %>% 
    mutate(Type = fct(Type), Year = as.character(Year))
  
  
  # ---- bind years 1 and 2 
  df2years <- bind_rows(year1_median, year2_median)
  
  
  # ---- plot median hours per month
  highchart() %>%
    hc_chart(type = "column",
             marginLeft = 200) %>%
    # hc_plotOptions(series = list(pointWidth = 16)) %>%
    hc_xAxis(categories = df2years$Type, labels = list(style = list(
      color = '#344a5e',fontFamily = "Segoe UI",fontWeight = 600), enabled = TRUE)) %>%
    hc_add_series(dataSorting = list(enabled = TRUE),
                  data = df2years, type = 'bar', hcaes(x = Type, y = `Median Hours`, group = Year),
                  dataLabels = list(enabled = FALSE, style = list(color ='#344a5e',
                                                                  fontFamily = "Segoe UI",
                                                                  fontWeight = 200))) %>%
    hc_title(text = title, align = "left",style = list(color ='#344a5e',
                                                       fontFamily = "Georgia",
                                                       fontWeight = 600)) %>% 
    
    hc_subtitle(text = "") %>%
    hc_caption(text = "Based on data") %>%
    hc_size(height = 550) %>%
    hc_add_theme(thm)
  
}
  


# ---- creating plot theme for highcharter 

thm <- hc_theme(colors =  c('#34495E', '#2ECC71','#3498DB', '#E74C3C','#E67E22','#9B59B6', '#F1C40F'),
                chart = list(backgroundColor = "#fff"),
                title = list(style = list(color ='#344a5e',
                                          fontFamily = "Georgia",
                                          fontWeight = 600)),
                subtitle = list(style = list(color ='#344a5e',
                                             fontFamily = "Segoe UI")),
                caption = list(style = list(color ='#344a5e',
                                            fontFamily = "Segoe UI")),
                # yAxis = list(labels = TRUE, style = list(fontSize = "14px")),
                legend = list(itemStyle = list(fontFamily ="Segoe UI", fontWeight = 300, color ='#344a5e')
                              ,itemHoverStyle = list(color ='gray')))



# ---- Make Cards ---- 
# ---- card-header 
cardHeader <- function(title) {
  h5(
    title,
    class = "ms-fontSize-10 ms-fontWeight-semibold",
    # style = "color: #32145A;"
    style = "color: #344a5e;"
  )
}

# ---- card 
Card <- function(title, content, size = "", style = "") {
  div(class = glue("card ms-depth-4 ms-fontSize-8 ms-fontWeight-bold ms-sm-fontSize-8 ms-xl-fontSize-8"),
      style = style,
      Stack(
        tokens = list(childrenGap = 5),
        Text(variant = "small", title, block = TRUE),
        content
      ))
}

testCard <- Card(
  "this is a test",
  p("test")
)

card1 <-  Card(
  tags$div(
    gridPanel(
      rows = "repeat(2 0.5fr)",
      gridPanel(
        rows = "1fr 1fr",
        gap = "0px",
        
        div(tags$br(),cardHeader("Imports")),
        div(class = "figure",
            textOutput("imports"))
      )
    )
  ),
  textOutput("imports")
)

card2 <- Card(
  tags$div(
    gridPanel(
      rows = "repeat(2 0.5fr)",
      gridPanel(
        rows = "1fr 1fr",
        gap = "0px",
        
        div(tags$br(),cardHeader("Exports")),
        div(class = "figure",
            textOutput("exports"))
      )
    )
  ),
  textOutput("exports")
)

card3 <- Card(
  tags$div(
    gridPanel(
      rows = "repeat(2 0.25fr 0.5fr)",
      gridPanel(
        rows = "0.25fr 0.75fr",
        gap = "0px",
        
        div(tags$br(),cardHeader("Indigenous Generation")),
        div(class = "figure3",
            textOutput("indig"))
      )
    )
  ),
  textOutput("indig")
)


card4 <- Card(
  tags$div(
    gridPanel(
      rows = "repeat(2 0.5fr)",
      gridPanel(
        rows = "1fr 1fr",
        gap = "0px",
        
        div(tags$br(),cardHeader("Total Generation")),
        div(class = "figure",
            textOutput("total_gen"))
      )
    )
  ),
  textOutput("total_gen")
)


# ---- layout
header_commandbar_list <- list(
  list(
    key = 'zoom_out',
    text = "", 
    iconProps = list(iconName = "")
  ),
  list(
    key = 'download',
    text = "", 
    iconProps = list(iconName = "")
  )
)
header <- flexPanel(
  id = "header",
  align_items = "center",
  flex = c(1, 1, 1),
  div(
    
  )
)



# ---- sidebar ----

# Custom rendering of group headers
navigation_styles <- list(
  root = list(
    height = "100%",
    width = "100%",
    boxSizing = "border-box"
    # border = "1px solid #eee",
    # overflowY = "auto"
  )
)

link_groups <- list(
  list(
    name = "",
    links = list(
      list(name = "A", url =  route_link("/"), key= 'key1', icon = 'Home'),
      list(name = "B", url = route_link("b"), key = 'key2', icon = 'AnalyticsReport'),
      list(name = "C", url = route_link("c"), key = 'key3', icon = 'GitGraph')
    )
  )
)


app_sidebar <- div(
  id = "sidebar",
  br(),
  Nav(
    groups = link_groups,
    selectedKey = "",
    styles = navigation_styles,
    onRenderGroupHeader = JS("group => React.createElement('h5', null, group.name)")
  ),
  Separator("Data"),
  div(
    style = "height: 1470px; overflow: auto;",
    uiOutput("table")
  )
)


app_footer <- flexPanel(
  id = "footer",
  justify_content = 'space-between',
  gap = "20px",
  Text(variant = "medium", "", block=TRUE),
  Text(variant = "medium", nowrap = FALSE, "Data "),
  Text(variant = "medium", nowrap = FALSE, "All rights reserved.")
)


# ---- create main page
main <- function(){
  tagList(div(class = "home-page",

              div(
                # ---- create grid layout
                gridPanel(
                  class = "mainPanel",
                  areas = c(
                    "area1 area1"
                    # "area2 area2"
                  )
                ),
                div(
                  class = "area1",
                  div(
                    div(
                      class = "main-text",
                      h4("Sub"),
                      h1("Header"),
                      p("Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's 
                        standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make 
                        a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, 
                        remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing 
                        Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of 
                        Lorem Ipsum. ")
                    ),
                    br(),
                  ),
                  
                  br(),
                  Separator(""),
                  div(class = "filters",
                      
                      gridPanel(
                        rows = "repeat(2 2fr)",
                        
                        gridPanel(
                          columns = "1fr 1fr",
                          gap = "5px",
                          
                          div(class = "filter1",
                              style = "display: flex; width: 100%; align-items: stretch;",
                              Stack(
                                tokens = list(childrenGap = 10),
                                horizontal = TRUE,
                                style = "flex-grow: 1",
                                DatePicker.shinyInput("fromDate", value = as.Date("2016/07/21"), label = "Select Time Period\n From"),
                                DatePicker.shinyInput("toDate", value = as.Date("2019/08/20"), label = "To")
                              )
                          ),
                          div(class = "filter2",
                              style = "height: 56px; display: flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content: flex-end; margin-bottom: 0px;",
                              Stack(
                                tokens = list(childrenGap = 0),
                                horizontal = TRUE,
                                materialSwitch(inputId = "switch", label = "")
                              )
                          )
                        ),
                      highchartOutput("stack")
                  ),
                      
                      gridPanel(
                        columns = "0.85fr 0.85fr 1.3fr 1fr",
                        gap = "5px",
                        
                        div(id = "sum_card",
                            card1),
                        div(id = "sum_card",
                            card2),
                        div(id = "sum_card",
                            card3),
                        div(id = "sum_card",
                            card3)
                      ),
                      
                      h4("Sub"),
                      h3("Header"),
                      p("Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's 
            standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make 
            a type "),
                      
                      div(
                        class = "area2",
                        tags$style(
                          ".subp {font-weight: 600;}"
                        ),
                        p(class = 'subp',"Compare across 2 different years"),
                        Stack(
                          className = "stack",
                          horizontal = TRUE,
                          numericInput("year1", label = "", value = 2017),
                          numericInput("year2", label = "", value = 2019)
                        ),
                        div(id = "years_plot",
                            highchartOutput("cluster_plot")
                        )
                      )
                  )
                )
              )
          )
  )
}


# ---- ui 

ui <- gridPage(
  
  tags$head(
    tags$link(href = "styles1.css", rel="stylesheet"),
    tags$script(href = "drilldown.js", type = "text/javascript")
  ),
  
  template = "grail-right-sidebar",
  gap = "0.3vw",
  rows = list(default = "50px 1fr 50px"), # 70px 1fr 30px
  
  
  header = div(header),
  sidebar = div(app_sidebar),
  content = div(main <- main()),
  footer = div(app_footer)
)





server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  
  # Plug router into shiny server
  shiny.router::router_server()
 
  
  # Reactive containing data after choosing date range
  data_react <- reactive({
    
    req(input$fromDate)
    req(input$toDate)
    
    data <- test
    data %>% filter(
      dates >= input$fromDate,
      dates <= input$toDate
    )
  })
  
  # create Table to show Data
  output$table <- renderUI({
    DetailsList(items = data_react(), columns = details_list_columns,
                checkboxVisibility = 2,  constrainMode = 0)
  })
  
  # ---- Calculate Sum Card outputs for display ----
  
  # ---- Imports calc
  output$imports <- renderText({
    req(input$fromDate)
    req(input$toDate)
    
    imports_num <- data_react() %>% select(`a`) %>% summarise(total_a = sum(a))
    paste(format(imports_num, big.mark = ","), "A")
  })
  
  # ---- Exports calc
  output$exports <- renderText({
    req(input$fromDate)
    req(input$toDate)
    
    exports_num <- data_react() %>% select(`b`) %>% summarise(total_b = sum(b))
    paste(format(exports_num, big.mark = ","), "B")
  })
  
  # ---- Indigenous Generation calc
  output$indig <- renderText({
    req(input$fromDate)
    req(input$toDate)
    
    indig_num <- data_react() %>% select(`c`) %>% summarise(total_c = sum(`c`))
    paste(format(indig_num, big.mark = ","), "C")
  })
  
  # ---- Switch between Stacked Graph and Line Chart ----
  
  # ---- Stacked BarChart 
  output$stack <- renderHighchart({
    # ---- pull reactive data
    data <- data_react()
    title <- "Hours per Product"
    
    if(input$switch == FALSE){
      line_graph(data, title)
    }
    else{
      stacked_chart(data, title)
    }
  })
  
  # ---- Create Reactive Expression to store year chosen in a var
  
  selected_year <- reactive(input$year1)
  selected_year_2 <- reactive(input$year2)
 
  # ---- pass reactive to filter function and plot output ----
  output$cluster_plot <- renderHighchart({
    year1 <- selected_year()
    year2 <- selected_year_2()
    
    title <- "Median Energy Generated by Fuel Type: GWh Year Comparison"
    
    plot_cluster(year1, year2, test2, title)
  })
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)

The only css affecting this draws the border box etc
.home-page, .2nd-page, .3rd-page {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: rgba(149, 157, 165, 0.2) 0px 1px 3px;

It references it in R Shiny function like this:
home_page <- function() {
  tagList(div(class = "home-page",
              
              div(
                p("This is a Test")
              )



What could be going on? Is it something to do with the CSS grid approach that I'm misusing via imola?
ui <- gridPage(

  tags$head(
    tags$link(href = "styles.css", rel="stylesheet"),
    tags$script(href = "drilldown.js", type = "text/javascript")
    ),

  template = "grail-right-sidebar",
  gap = "0.3vw",
  rows = list(default = "50px 1fr 50px"), # 70px 1fr 30px

  
  header = div(header),
  sidebar = div(app_sidebar),
  content = div( 
    router_ui(
      route("/", home_page),
      route("page_2", page_2),
      route("page_3", page_3)
    )
  ),
  footer = div(app_footer)

)
